# Prestashop 1.7 white page

Tags: prestashop, plesk, prestashop-1.7

I have to migrate my prestashop 1.7 to another sever because the OVH crash.

but i have blank page in back and front office.
No error display with debug mode.

PHP version : 7.1 (apache server with plesk)

any idea ?

warning :

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../psr/log/Psr/Log/LogLevel.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/tools/htmlpurifier/standalone:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel' not found in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Debug.php on line 56

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../psr/log/Psr/Log/LogLevel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.be/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Prestashop ?

The error is clear, a core Prestashop file is missing :

```
/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LogLevel.php
```

You have to restore it by taking it from the ZIP of the same version.

My two cents: you are restoring on a backup where "log*" was excluded and this caused the files containing the word log not to be backed up... so check that everything else is intact!